# Create function to automatically create dataset from summary(fit <- lm( y ~ x1 + x2 +… xn)

Tags: r, data-binding, summary, linear-regression

This question is closely related to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747624/create-function-to-automatically-create-plots-from-summaryfit-lm-y-x1-x2). The only difference is that instead of plotting the data, I want the raw data behind fit. I tried to solve it myself following the last answer but still got stuck.

So I want to retrieve from the fit of a linear regression, the independent variables, the fitted variable, the residual and standardized residual.

I will use the example, which was kindly created by Brian Diggs. So thank you.

```
dat <- data.frame(x1=rnorm(100), x2=rnorm(100,4,5), x3=rnorm(100,8,27), x4=rnorm(100,- 6,0.1),t=(1:100)+runif(100,-2,2)) 
dat <- transform(dat,  y=x1+4*x2+3.6*x3+4.7*x4+rnorm(100,3,50))

fit <- lm(y~x1+x2+x3+x4, data=dat)  # fit
dat$resid <- residuals(fit)
vars <- names(coef(fit))[-1]
```

The next step I am stuck, as before. I am trying to get only the variables which are used for the regression and bind them to a new dataset. I attempted the following, but it does not work. This step is wrong. I can bind residuals, fitted but not the variables used.

```
fit.data <- cbind(predict(fit),as.name(names(coef(fit))[2]))
```

Any help is really appreciated. Yes, still teaching R myself.

Comment: Do you mean the actual data? Why don't you just get that from `dat`, like this: `dat[,vars]`?

Comment: Thank you Nick. You are right, I could use `dat`. Unfortunately we are looking at a dataset which has got blank fields for some variables and not for others. Those blank fields will then be excluded. `na.omit()` would achieve this. So I can bind the variables used in the regression. All the variables have the same length. Then apply `na.omit()`. This should in fact give the same dataset as the regression ultimately uses. From an auditing perspective I am still quite curious to compare the dataset create by 'na.omit' and 'dat' versus the underlying fit data.

Comment: You should definitely check out `fortify` from the `ggplot2` package ...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cbind together things which are not of corresponding dimension. For that purpose you need a list. You also will want to work with the fit object since the summary object does not have the fitted values (and maybe would not work with rstandard() but I'm not sure about that).

```
mod.results <- list(vars = names(coef(fit))[-1],
                    fitted.values=fit$fitted.values, 
                    residuals = residuals(fit), 
                    std.resid = rstandard(fit))
```

Putting it in a function is trivial:

```
> extr.res <- function(fit) {mod.results <- list(vars = names(coef(fit)), 
fitted.values=fit$fitted.values, residuals = residuals(fit), std.resid = rstandard(fit)) }
> str(extr.res(fit))
List of 4
 $ vars         : chr [1:5] "(Intercept)" "x1" "x2" "x3" ...
 $ fitted.values: Named num [1:100] -36.19 31.4 -2.59 -130.03 -1.12 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:100] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 $ residuals    : Named num [1:100] -71.6 -21.2 -50.7 19 -58.5 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:100] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 $              : Named num [1:100] -1.608 -0.487 -1.175 0.435 -1.297 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:100] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
```

Comment: Thank you DWin. I see the data for residuals and fitted, but not the actual data behind vars ie for x1 or x2 and so forth. So I am not capturing the data of the independent variables from the regression.

Comment: If you want answers that address handling missing values then you should not offer an example with complete data. Please edit your question to accurately reflect your problem.